A tricky question about cybercrime
Let’s say I hack into a database when I’m in America, but the database servers are physically in Iran, but to complicate it even more- the company that owns the database is European.
These are just examples, but my example includes the three main factors:
-Location of prosecutor
-Location of server
-Location of company/ owner
I am not talking about how much trouble they’d get in- or what jurisdictions- because this is not what I’m asking. Each country would have their own laws for cybercrime-
But my question: In the example I provided- whose country’s laws would you be subject to? Or in any situation, really, where the three factors- or even two- don’t match.

all of them
Doing anything on the internet happens in at least two locations as far as the law is concerned: Wherever the sender is and where the receiver is. Like with a phone call, both sides laws apply.
As a typical example: Selling a product from the USA to Germany, you automagically have to abide by US export regulations, German import regulations, German warranty laws, and (if that is more than a once-off and atypical for your company) also the GDPR.
Now, your example happens in the USA and Iran, and damages European-owned widgets. The company owning the widget can sue civilly in its own or the relevant US state or federal court. Iran, US, and the company's country can prosecute the perpetrator criminally. Whoever happens to catch the perpetrator physically will have the best chance to prosecute first, unless extradition happens. Unless there is a treaty between the countries, more than one can prosecute too: It's different sovereigns, they are independent!

Thanks very much for the answer! That makes sense. Can you understand why my question has been downvoted- I am not accusing you- I am just slightly confused because this is a legitimate and well thought out question! (Or I think!)

It's rather basic and nothing complicated at all, not tricky or intricate or complex. It's rather simple: you need to abide by all laws in all countries you do business in.

It’s also a question that’s been asked and answered many times here in different forms.

It may also have been downvoted because of all the unnecessary prefatory rambling, which I've removed for you.

This said, the place where the server is located is typically given much less importance than IT people expect. Even if the place where the server is located can provide a jurisdictional hook, usually choice of law analysis will focus on the location of the perpetrator and the victim.
